# How to find Java path via Cmake on Mac

Tags: cmake, java-home

I am currently having issues with getting my code to get Java libraries on mac.

This is the error i get keep getting when compiling:

`\-- Java version check failed: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-18.0.1.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -version returned an error: ""`

This indirectly sets `${JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH}`, `${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS}` and other java paths to '`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-18.0.1.1.jdk/Contents/Home`.

The problem is `jdk-18.0.1.1.jdk` no longer exist on my system, so how do i make my code use another java jdk version.

I tried installing jdk 1.8 and tried exporting the locatino of the in the zsh shell like this:

`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8.0_292)`

However the only way i get my code to run is when i point the java path to the exact location, like this:

```
set(JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include")
set(JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include")
set(JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include/darwin")
set(JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/lib/libjawt.dylib")
set(JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/lib/server/libjvm.dylib")
```

Comment: Does this issue go away if you blow awake the CMake build dir? This sounds like a CMakeCache issue.

Comment: @Botje Thank you. Deleting the build folder worked.